# Detect when in BigPictureMode

Tags: c#, windows-services, wmi, steam

I am trying to execute some commands as soon as Steam BigPictureMode is started. I trief WMI, but the problem is, that "steam.exe" is running all the time and BigPictureMode is started inside this process. So watching processes with WMI did not help. I have absolutely no idea how to accomplish this.

Note: The BigPictureMode is started by holding the guide button of the xbox360 controller. Now I want my PC to automatically switch some settings.

Does anyone have an idea? Would love to use c#.